# How to sort a pi_list_query (or pi_exec_query) listing

Tags: typo3

I am using the extension feuserlisting to present my visitors a list of site members, but I'd like to sort the list on the full name. I know I can click the table heading to sort it when it is presented on the screen, but somehow it should be possible to set the default sorting by TypoScript?

Answer (score 0):

The way of doing it is to use the _DEFAULT_PI_VARS mechanism.

```
plugin.tx_feuserlisting_pi1._DEFAULT_PI_VARS {
    sort = name:0
}
```

The list view method of feuserlisting initilizes with a call to `$this->pi_setPiVarDefaults()` (which is inherited from tslib_pibase), where the key `_DEFAULT_PI_VARS` is taken into account when establishing the piVars.

This technique should be available in all pibase extensions which initialize their piVars with such a call.